# How can I delete the least common int in a list in rounds?

Tags: python, list

I've got a list like

[1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4]

I want to do code that will first remove 3 from the list (as it only appears once), then print the list. Then remove 2 from the list as it only appears twice. ETC..
So for a list of length n, remove the least common int in rounds until the most common element is all thats left in the list

I know an easy way to do it would just be to return the int that appears the most  frequently however my brief wants this...

Comment: put the key and its count into a min heap. Then start removing the entry from min heap, read its key and then remove that key from the list

Comment: Use `collections.Counter` to get the numbers in order of frequency with the  `most_common` method, reverse it, then iterate through it one by one, removing or filtering the items from the original list in turn?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a free coding service. Provide a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def removeLeast(arr):
    data = {}
    for i in arr:
        if i not in data:
            data[i] = 1
        else:
            data[i]+=1
    data = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

    for i in range(len(data)-1):
        x = data[i]
        for j in range(x[1]):
            arr.remove(x[0])
        print(arr)
```